# add attrs to a relationship model field on django forms

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

hi all need help adding some style to a relationship field on django form.

have this

models.py

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    idEmpresa= models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    nombreEmpresa = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Cliente(models.Model):
    idCliente = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=9)
    nombreCliente = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
    empresa= models.ForeignKey(Empresa, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
```

forms.py

```
class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = '__all__'

    widgets = {
        'idCliente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'id': 'idCliente',                  'name': 'idCliente', 'type': 'text'}),
        'nombreCliente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'id': 'nombreCliente', 'name': 'nombreCliente', 'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'Ingrese nombre y apellidos', 'maxlength': '64'}),
            
}
```

and I need to add the attrs to the field empresa on my ClienteForm...

try this

```
'empresa' : forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=empresa, widget=('class' : 'form-select')),
```

and this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["empresa"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-select", 'id' : 'empresasss'})
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, have read the documentation several times but I'm stuck, real stuck at this.

help me please!!!

Comment: What is your expected result? And what are you getting instead?

Comment: in the html rendered i am getting the select field but no styles added.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get a solution using javascript by adding an EventListener and changing the attribute to the select.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="empresa" class="form-label">Empresa:</label>
    {{form.empresa}}
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const item = document.getElementById('id_empresa');
            item.setAttribute('class', 'form-select');
            });
        </script>
</div>
```